# How to close DOM Window jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In example 3 on the below mentioned link 
http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html

Can you add a link within the window to close it?

`Window.close()`, `self.close()` and `parent.window.removechid()` aren't working

I think they have modified the functionality of `close()` in jQuery.DOMwindow.js

Plz help.

Comment: what is the error throwned?

Comment: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it. I.e. if your user has browsed to your page of their own accord, you cannot close the window. If you open a window for the user, you can close *that* window

Comment: According to the first line under the title of your linked page, you have to call `$(selector).closeDOMWindow({options})`. The methods you are using are from the `window` object, and as correctly stated by @Jonathan, would only work on other windows opened from the `window.open()` method, but this is unrelated to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `DOMwindow.js`, or could you do something like this?

```js
$('#myButt').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').fadeIn();
});

/* Close when user clicks on X, or on overlay: */
$('#x, #myModal').click(function(){
  $('#myModal').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;}
#myModal{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  text-align:center;
  background:black;opacity:0.8;
  z-index:999; /* Ensure this dialog overlays all else */
  display:none;
}
#modalInner{
  position:relative;
  top:10vh;
  height:70vh;width:80vw;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#modalTop{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;overflow:hidden;}
  #mtL{float:left;height:20px;width:65vw;}
  #mtR{float:left;height:20px;width:10vw;text-align:center;}
    #x{width:20px;text-align:center;background:white;color:darkcyan;}
    #x:hover{background:darkcyan;color:white;cursor:pointer;}

#msg{position:relative;bottom:90px;width:50vw;margin:0 auto;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myModal">
  <div id="modalInner">
    <div id="modalTop">
      <div id="mtL"></div><div id="mtR"><div id="x">x</div></div>
    </div>
    
    <iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
    
    <div id="msg">This is an IFRAME. Google webpage should appear in here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myButt">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: See update to answer. (Added `$('#x, #myModal')` and `z-index:999`)