# Light box div display over Bootstrap grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create my own light box.

I am struggling to figure out how to cause the light box `div` to appear on top of my Bootstrap grid because I don't know where to place it in my `html` file.

My grid looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid content">           
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-md-9"> </div>

            <div class="col-md-3"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the light box `div`:

```
<div id="lightbox">
    <p>Click to close</p>
    <div id="content">
        <img src="#" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the `css` for the light box `div`:

```
#lightbox {
    position:fixed;
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7); 
    text-align:center;
}
```

When an event occurs, I will use JavaScript to unhide my light box `div`. 
Currently it is not displaying on top of the Bootstrap columns and I don't know how to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `CSS` to your lightbox styling to ensure it sits on top!

```
z-index: 9999;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the light box at the top of your body. Style it as:

```
position:fixed;top:20vw;left:30vh;width:20vh;z-index:999;
```

*(Of course, all top/left/width/height values are whatever works for you)*

See this example:

[How to close DOM Window jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038945/how-to-close-dom-window-jquery/38039312#38039312)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do work, but may be harder to track because both rely exlusively on z-index.

I find it best to rely on z-index as little as possible, because eventually you may have so many z-index definitions that you will have to start tracking them all.

All DOM elements receive an imlicit z-index based on their positioning in the DOM markup code, with those elements being defined last, as having a "higher" z-index (although not explicitly defined). This means that the elements at the "bottom" of the markup file, will appear "above" the elements defined prior to it.

So I would suggest putting all lightbox/modal type elements at the end of the HTML file to start with. This will mean, that if you define no z-index anywhere else, those elements will visually appear on top.

But you are also using Bootstrap, which explicitly defines many z-index's for several of its components (like navbars etc). If, however, you [use Bootstraps `modal` components](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), it will inherit the top level z-index defined in the Bootstrap framework.

Both putting the lightbox element at the end of the HTML file, and applying Bootstrap's standard z-indexing using the built-in `modal` components, you should create reliable visual layering of the lightbox.